# jquery change select to checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

in my form, I would like to change, with one click on a link, a select to a list of checkbox with the same choice that the previous select.
I already did with a show/hidden div but the matter is the selection of the hide part is still active and mess up with the results. 
So I don't know how to handle this and that's why I ask for your help.

Thanks

Comment: please provide a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ for what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disabled element select or you could remove its name attribute. Here is a sample snippet:

```
$('#mylink').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#myselect').prop('disabled','disabled').hide();
    $('#myselect option').each(function(){
         $('#mylist').append('<input type="checkbox" value="'+$(this).val()+'">'+$(this).val()+'</input>');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I needed something like that !

Answer (score 0):

You can simply disable elements when hiding, then values of disabled elements will not be posted