# Convert Selection box to checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having troubles in getting selection box value inside jQuery. I want selection box value inside check box change of function. ie:

inside

```html
$('input').on('change', function()  //need selection box value here
});
```

```html
<select class="selectclass" id="id" >
 <option  value="22" >option1</option>   
  <option  value="33" >option21</option> 
</select>
```

Gone through the stackoverflow questions like these but could'nt get what I want

[jquery change select to checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13265735/jquery-change-select-to-checkbox)

etc...

Comment: `Convert Selection box to checkbox` or `getting selection box value` ??

Comment: @Pedram converting and getting selct box value .I tried to get the selection box value inside checkbox onchange function but its not working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go, you can convert `select option` to `checkbox` on `change`

```js
$('select').on('change', function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  $('<input/>').attr({
  type: 'checkbox',
  value: val
  }).appendTo('#check');
  console.log(val);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="selectclass" id="id">
 <option  value="22" >option1</option>   
  <option  value="33" >option21</option> 
</select>
<div id="check"></div>
```

Or without `change` function, just `onload`

```js
$('select option').each(function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  $('<input/>').attr({
    type: 'checkbox',
    value: val
  }).appendTo('#check');
})

$('input').on('change', function() {
  alert(this.value);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="selectclass" id="id">
 <option  value="22" >option1</option>   
  <option  value="33" >option21</option> 
</select>
<div id="check"></div>
```

Comment: i need that value inside $('input').on('change', function()  //need selection box value here
});

Comment: You have `select` and then want to select it by `input` ? odd. @DingoGhatr

Comment: @DingoGhatr See second example, try to change `checkbox`, you get `value` , is it what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Here is code to break out the values and show labels.

```js
$('select#selectid option').each(function() {
  var val = $(this).val();

$("#check").append('<input type="checkbox" value="'+$(this).val()+'">'+$(this).val()+'</input>');
   })

$('#selectid').prop('disabled','disabled').hide();

$('input').on('change', function(){
  alert(this.value);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="selectclass" id="selectid">
 <option  value="22" >option1</option>   
  <option  value="33" >option21</option> 
</select>
<div id="check"></div>
```